# Using Turtle in python, how could one make an amount of shapes be drawn based off of user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

In Python using Turtle, how could i have a specific amount of shapes print based off of user input? So if i wanted 8 circles to be drawn from input how could i get the code to do that?

Comment: Do you know how to draw a single shape?  What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: Wecome to StackExchange. Your question is not quite clear. Do you mean you want to input a positive integer from the user then show that many circles? Or do you mean you want the user to choose the kind of shape? Or something else?

Comment: Yeah i can draw single shapes, the problem i am having is a program that draws a certain amount of shapes using user input to determine the size of the shapes and the amount of shapes being outputted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  It will draw a line of circles based on a user entered radius and count.

```
import turtle

# get the user input
size = float(input('Enter a size for your shape: ')) # radius of circle
number = int(input('Enter a number:')) # number of shapes to draw

for i in range(number):
    # draw a circle
    turtle.circle(size)

    # move over so they dont overlap
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.fd(size*2)
    turtle.pendown()
```